# Refresh page positions on pre selected div

Tags: jquery

I have JQuery that slides divs horizontally. In those divs I have objects which requires web page to be reloaded if they change. Problem is, for example, if I change object which is in div with #page3,  reload throws me back on div with #page1 as it is selected by default on web page load. How to achieve that when user change object on #page3 div, #page3 div remains selected after page reload.

JQUERY:

```
 jQuery(function ($) {
    $('a.panel').click(function () {
        var $page = $($(this).attr('href')),
            $other = $page.siblings('.active');
        if (!$page.hasClass('active')) {
            $other.each(function (index, self) {
                var $this = $(this);
                $this.removeClass('active').animate({
                    left: $this.width()
                }, 500);
            });
            $page.addClass('active').show().css({
                left: -($page.width())
            }).animate({
                left: 0
            }, 500);
        }
        return false;
    });
    $('a.panel:nth(0)').click();
});
```

Comment: Does it really have to be refreshed or can you load the new content with ajax?

Comment: did you try changing window.location?

Comment: @JonasGrumann Im building report in SAP BW Web application designer, using html, jquery to put many individual reports in single web page. Since its executed on BW Server I think it must be refreshed since its refreshing report.

Comment: @Kuro Im not really familiar with JS or JQ library, since Im SAP BW consultant, but I was in a need for JQ here so barely managed to put this sliding div code together, so I would need more info on what you mean.

Comment: Did you code the slider yourself or is a plugin or something?

Comment: Myself with the help of stackoverflow community

Answer (score 0):

send the id of div or index of the panel being changed back to server as a query parameter. Send back this value when page reloads in url's query parameter. Then just extract that value on page load from the url and select the said div using javascript or jquery.

Comment: I have no way of interacting with url and passing variables through it because it comes out of sap bw server. Could I do something like, store <a> tag that's active before page reload and select it after reload using jquery?

Comment: then just store the value in a local cookie and read it from there when page loads. You will find jquery plugins to work with cookies.

Comment: I figured something like that must be done, but as I said to Kuro in my previous comments, I'm not very familiar with js or jq so I really need some help here.

Comment: add [this](https://github.com/carhartl/jquery-cookie) jquery plugin to your page. Then set a cookie when you are leaving page or when object change occurs : $.cookie('the_cookie', 'the_value'); Then read it back using $.cookie('the_cookie'); and select the corresponding element in page.